# MAMP Pro crashes whilst starting Apache if no internet connection present?

Tags: mamp, mamp-pro

I've used MAMP Pro for years and never experienced this issue, until the last week or so. I haven't installed any updates for MacOS or MAMP Pro in that time.

On starting MAMP Pro the servers start to boot, MySQL fires up fine and before Apache can start properly the whole MAMP App crashes.

I'll not post the full crash report for fear of sending readers to sleep, however here is what I have worked out as the failing thread...

```
    Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

    Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
    Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
    Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

    Application Specific Information:
    abort() called

    Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6d9fefce __pthread_kill + 10
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6db3c150 pthread_kill + 333
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff6d95b30a abort + 127
    3   net.hockeyapp.sdk.mac           0x000000010b5a3c02 uncaught_exception_handler + 27
    4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff4633fbd2 __handleUncaughtException + 770
    5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff6ccc4a41 _objc_terminate() + 91
    6   net.hockeyapp.sdk.mac           0x000000010b591417 BITCrashUncaughtCXXTerminateHandler() + 766
    7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff6b95b7c9 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
    8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff6b95b843 std::terminate() + 51
    9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff6d875e9c _dispatch_client_callout + 28
    10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff6d881471 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1148
    11  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff46268b99 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    12  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff4622b44a __CFRunLoopRun + 2586
    13  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff4622a797 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 487
    14  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff4553f866 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 286
    15  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff4553f5d6 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 613
    16  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff4553f354 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 64
    17  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff4383ca23 _DPSNextEvent + 2085
    18  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff43fd1e6c -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 3044
    19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff43831831 -[NSApplication run] + 764
    20  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff438009d2 NSApplicationMain + 804
    21  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff6d8af145 start + 1
```

Has anyone else experienced this, or can offer an explanation of how I might be able to fix it? I work offline a lot so not being able to fire up MAMP is a game changer.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

My issue is this: When connected to the web, Mamp freezes and takes several minutes just to load pages. As soon as I disconnect from the web- it loads pages immediately.

I've Flushed DNS, cleared caches etc all to no avail. I'm on a Macbook, tried editing etc/hosts and still nothing. Didn't change anything yet it all just came out of nowhere.

Frustrating and can't work properly like this.